# Tips for golfing in Wren

Tags: code-golf, tips

[Wren](https://wren.io/) is a small, fast, class-based concurrent scripting language. Does anyone have any tips for this language?

Please make sure to post 1 tip per answer, and don't post answers like "remove whitespace".

Answer (score 2):

## `String.fromByte`

Instead of the standard `String.fromCodePoint(x)`, a method that saves a whole 5 bytes is:

```
String.fromByte
```

Answer (score 0):

In most cases `true` can be written `1` and `false` can be written `!1`